# Getting QGIS Project data from outside Python script

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, standalone, qgs

In my project, I have to connect .Net with the QGIS app, so I need to know
how an outside script can get data from QGIS.

I can run this script from .Net perfectly:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

from qgis.utils import *

import sys
import os


def main ():
    # Create a reference to the QgsApplication.
    # Setting the second argument to True enables the GUI.  We need
    # this since this is a custom application.

    strRuta = r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.11\apps\qgis-ltr"
    os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX_PATH'] = strRuta

    # load providers
    qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
    # Supply the path to the qgis install location

    qgs.setPrefixPath(strRuta, True)
    qgs.initQgis()

    # QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.11\apps\qgis-ltr", True)

    QMessageBox.warning(None, "AVISO", QgsApplication.showSettings())

    project = QgsProject.instance()
    listLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('MONTE')
    QMessageBox.information(None, "Aviso monte:", str(len(listLayers)))

    # Write your code here to load some layers, use processing
    # algorithms, etc.

    # Finally, exitQgis() is called to remove the
    # provider and layer registries from memory
    qgs.exitQgis()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, in this line `QMessageBox.information(None, "Aviso monte:", str(len(listLayers)))`, I obtain 0, but I have charged a MONTE layer in qgis manually without code

I am using QGIS 3.22.11.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

You have to load a project. `QgsProject.instance()` returns the empty project, because you didn't load any project.

Add this line: `project.read("c:/path/to/project.qgz")`

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read("c:/path/to/project.qgz")
listLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('MONTE')
QMessageBox.information(None, "Aviso monte:", str(len(listLayers)))
```

Comment: Yes, but I have some layers in qgis that I have imported from postgis, and I would like to make some operations with them in this script. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How can I access to the project and the layers that are charged in qgis from this script ?